# Sync Databases Mirroring /replication/log shipping

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need help in this scenario. We have one SQl server, I need to maintain two databases of this server in another physically far location.
Just the exact copy not like failover. Just the same data so that if some thing happens on one, other should also be up but not like automatic failover or anything.
Just to sync databases that whatever happened in primary should be synced with other. I am very confused that what should I use, replication, mirroring, log shipping.

Can anyone advice?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replication does not maintain an identical copy of the database, it only replicates selected tables.

This leaves mirroring or log shipping:

- **Delay**: Mirroring will keep the two replicas more close to the current master copies (will always try to be up to date, continuously). Log shipping has a built-in operational delay due to the log backup frequency, usually around 15-30 minutes or so.
- **Multiple copies**: mirroring allows for exactly one replica copy. Log shipping allows for multiple copies.
- **Replica access**: mirroring does not allow access to the replica. You can create database snapshots on the secondary server and the snapshots can be accesses. Log shipping allows read-only access to the replica copy, but will disconnect all users when applying the next backup log received (eg. every 15-30 minutes).
- **Ease of setup**: this point is subjective, but I say log shipping is easier to set up (easier to understand)
- **Ease of operation**: same as above, subjective, I would again say log shipping just because is easier to troubleshoot.
- **Security**: log shipping requires file copy access, which requires a VPN or similar setup. Mirroring can work with [certificate based security](http://rusanu.com/2008/10/23/how-does-certificate-based-authentication-work/) and traverse domains w/o trust, so it does not require a VPN.

Of course, you still have to make your own decision, based on your criteria.

Comment: Thanks much for reply! after reading lot about everything I also thought to go with log shipping. Thanks very much for explanation.

Answer (score 1):

To the Above query, try to keep your SQL servers on the same port. Have that port openend on the Firewall and try to ping each the servers from one domain to another. This shopuld help. Try and revet if you are facing issues.